# How to add another checkbox with the click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

So far I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset = "utf-8">
 <title>Project</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="checkbox">
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">

    </div><!-- /input-group -->
    <button id="btnId">Add</button>
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

</div><!-- /.row -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = document.getElementById('btnId');
    btn.onclick = function(){
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea"); 
    btn.parentNode.insertBefore(txt, btn);
    return false;
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It starts off with the checkbox and textfield however when I click the "Add" button I would like it to create another checkbox and textfield that is exactly the same. I have it so that right now it creates just a textarea.Anyone know how I could change my javascript code so that it creates an additional checkbox and textfield every time I press the Add button?

Comment: Hello! You should paste your project at jsfiddle.net and post the link, so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `createElement` method takes the tag name as an argument, so you should be using `"input"` instead of `"textarea"`.

But if you wanted to copy the entire `input-group` div and its content, then it'll be easier to use `.cloneNode(true)` to store a copy of the original in memory, then use `.cloneNode(true)` again to create new ones.

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btnId');
var group = btn.previousElementSibling.cloneNode(true);
btn.onclick = function() {
    this.parentNode.insertBefore(group.cloneNode(true), this);

    return false;
};
```

*(Passing `true` to `.cloneNode()` causes its descendants to be cloned as well, which is what you want here.)*

---

Note the `.previousElementSibling` isn't supported in IE8 and lower, but we need to deal with the text node properly. To support older IE, make a function like this:

```
function previousElementSibling(el) {
    while (el && (el = el.previousSibling) && el.nodeType !== 1) {
    }
    return el
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var group = previousElementSibling(btn).cloneNode(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// create container DIV
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('class', 'input-group-addon');

// append it to your button container
btn.parentNode.insertBefore(div, btn); 

// create checkbox
var chk = document.createElement("input"); 
chk.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');

// append it to the DIV you just created
btn.parentNode.insertBefore(chk, div);        

// create text input
var txt = document.createElement("input"); 
txt.setAttribute('type', 'text');

// append it to the DIV you just created
btn.parentNode.insertBefore(txt, div);
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FwjeV/))

Comment: `div.className = 'input-group-addon'` works also in older browsers.